# how to move simple view in self boundary of simulator of iphone infinitely without animation in objective c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.3, cgpoint

I want to move my `UIView` of size `(x=50,y=50)` in the boundary of simulator screen means rectangular without animation infinitely.

Comment: sorry @Mayur my mistake it is UIView Not NSView thank you because i'm new in iphone now i'm learning from only 15 days.please vote up my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To moving view continuously in your simulator boundary you have to put logic there is no predefined method without animation. if you are using animation then  below given link is useful. [How to repeat animation from current state not from startingstate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22471489/1516939) or without animation the below code will help you.
And yes please note that **

- pos

** is a object of CGPoint class and you don't have to allocate it simply declare in interface.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{

```
 pos  = v1.center;
NSLog(@"POSITION === %f",pos.x);

 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(rotateBoundary)
                               userInfo:nil
                                repeats:YES];

[super viewDidLoad];


 //[self performSelector:@selector(rotateBoundary) withObject:self afterDelay:5.0];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
```

}

-(void)rotateBoundary
{

```
if (pos.x>=20 && pos.x<=290 && pos.y==25) 
{      
    NSLog(@"Top left to right.");
    pos.x+=5;
    v1.center = pos;
    NSLog(@"pos.x   ===  %f",pos.x);
}
if(pos.x >= 290 && pos.y<=430)
{
    NSLog(@"Right top to down.");
    pos.y+=5;
    v1.center = pos;
    NSLog(@"pos.y   ===  %f",pos.y);
}

if(pos.y == 430 && pos.x>=20) 
{
    NSLog(@"Down right to left.");
    pos.x-=5;
    v1.center = pos;
    NSLog(@"pos.x   ===  %f",pos.x);
}
if (pos.x <= 20 && pos.y>=25) 
{
    NSLog(@"Down left to top.");
    pos.y-=5;
    v1.center = pos;
    NSLog(@"pos.y   ===  %f",pos.y);
}
```

}

Comment: In that v1 is NSView and (void)rotateBoundary is instance method declared in our header file. v1.center is a center point of the view. And please take view of size (50*50) and if it execute properly then you can take other size and you can set the points of x and y as your need.